# Using pipe in @App doesn't work - ionic 2

Tags: typescript, ionic2

I'm trying to use pipes for translation in ionic2. When using it in @Page it works as expected but as soon trying to use a pipe added directly in @App it doesn't. Is "pipes" attribute not supported in @App?

```
@App({
  templateUrl: 'build/app.html',
  pipes: [TranslatePipe]  
})
```

Part of app.html

```
<ion-menu id="leftMenu" [content]="content">

  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>Pages</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>

  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <button ion-item *ngFor="#p of pages" (click)="openPage(p)">
        {{ p.title | translate }}
      </button>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>

</ion-menu>
```

Complete example is found on github -> https://github.com/cyrillzadra/MyIonic2ProjectTranslateIssue

Thanks for help.
cyrill

Comment: according to the documentation it is supported. http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/decorators/App/ . what is the behaviour you are experiencing though? are there any errors?

Comment: All {{ 'key' | translate }} in app template are shown as empty. Using the same  in page template it works. There are no errors in javascript console.

Comment: it works for me - after cloning repo, fixing some build issues (ie go with ionic 2 beta.1 and angular 2 beta.6 and fix one typing issue) then I can change `test: 'Hello'` and can see the change on the left menu.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will help

```
{{p.title | translate:''}}
```

repo with TranslationService and TranslationPipe
https://github.com/philipphalder/ionic2-rc3-NG2-Translate